# Homotopically vs geometrically atoroidal

Tags: geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

In the book

*Aschenbrenner, Matthias; Friedl, Stefan; Wilton, Henry*, [**3-manifold groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4171/154), EMS Series of Lectures in Mathematics. Zürich: European Mathematical Society (EMS) (ISBN 978-3-03719-154-5/pbk). xiv, 215 p. (2015). [ZBL1326.57001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1326.57001).

they say that a $3$-manifold $M$ is *(homotopically) atoroidal* if any map $T^2\to M$ from a torus that induces an injection $\pi_1(T^2)\to\pi_1(M)$ is homotopic to a map $T^2\to\partial M$.

A related definition is that $M$ is *(geometrically) atoroidal* if any incompressible embedded $T^2\subset M$ is isotopic to a boundary component of $M$.

According to the book, these two notions agree except for "small Seifert fibered manifolds," where "a Seifert fibered manifold is called *small* if it is not Haken."  And, "a $3$-manifold is *Haken* [...] if it is compact, orientable, irreducible, and has an embedded incompressible surface," where "embedded surface" means properly embedded and orientable.

Let $X$ be a [pair of pants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_of_pants_(mathematics)) (a closed $3$-times punctured sphere) and let $M=S^1\times X$.

- This is not homotopically atoroidal.  If $a,b$ are generators of $\pi_1(X)$ with, say, counterclockwise orientation around the punctures, then let $\gamma$ represent the loop $ab^{-1}$, which requires a point of intersection.  The immersed torus $S^1\times \gamma$ is $\pi_1$-injective but not boundary parallel.  If it were boundary parallel, then this would give a homotopy of $\gamma$ to $\partial X$.
- This is geometrically atoroidal.  Essentially, every simple closed curve in $X$ is boundary parallel in the surface.
- This is a Seifert-fibered space since it is an $S^1$ product bundle over the surface $X$.
- This is Haken, so not a *small* Seifert-fibered space.  $\{*\}\times X$ is a properly embedded orientable incompressible surface. (It is $\pi_1$-injective.)

In [the arXiv version of the survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.0202) from a couple years before the book, they had previously written that "these two notions differ only for certain Seifert fibered $3$-manifolds where the base orbifold is a genus $0$ surface such that the number of boundary components together with the number of cone points equals three."  $M$ is certainly such a Seifert fibered space, and I have been puzzled by the difference.

**What is the correct condition for when the notions of a space being homotopically and geometrically atoroidal diverge?**  Or what have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the only class of compact 3-manifolds where you see the difference between the two notions consists of **small Seifert manifolds**.

Their book definition of small Seifert manifolds, as you correctly noticed, is wrong: The non-Haken condition is too strong. (It is correct though if you only consider oriented closed manifolds.) Instead they should have asked for "no **essential** closed incompressible surfaces." Here an incompressible surface is called essential if it is not boundary-parallel. However, this condition as stated is useless for your purposes since non-existence of essential incompressible tori is exactly what you are trying to characterize.

Their arxiv definition of a small Seifert manifold is correct as long as you restrict to the class of oriented 3-manifolds. If you allow nonorientable 3-manifolds then, for instance, the product of the Klein bottle  with the interval  would have to be excluded as well (and few more examples where the base is a non-orientable Euclidean orbifold). A better way to proceed is to strengthen the requirement of geometric atoroidality: In addition to tori, require that every incompressible 2-sided Klein bottle is inessential (i.e. is boundary-parallel).

Comment: I suppose a motivation for my question was that I had a hard time finding what the definition of a small Seifert-fibered space was (for example: are the "special" Seifert manifolds on page 155 of Jaco's book the "small" ones?).  With the pair of pants example I give, the pants form an essential incompressible surface, correct? So, to clarify, small SFS's are characterized by having no essential *closed* 2-sided incompressible surfaces? (I'm emphasizing the word that excludes the pants example.)

Comment: @KyleMiller Right.

Comment: Ok, thank you Prof. @MoisheCohen

Comment: @KyleMiller: A small correction: In the context of my answer "small" means "no essential closed 2-sided incompressible torus". There might be a closed horizontal incompressible surface of higher genus (if the Euler number of Seifert fibration is zero).