# Hyperbolization theorem for closed, reducible manifolds

Tags: geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, low-dimensional-topology, ricci-flow

[Ashenbrenner et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.0202.pdf) state the Hyperbolisation theorem as follows

> Let $N$ be a compact, orientable, irreducible $3$-manifold with empty or toroidal boundary. If $N$ is atoroidal and $π_1(N)$ is infinite, then $N$ is hyperbolic.

But in the following remark they say that (1) *any closed atoroidal 3-manifold with infinite fundamental group is hyperbolic*, as a consequence of [Leeb et al. Theorem H](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0801.0803.pdf)

> Any smooth action by a finite group on a closed hyperbolic 3–manifold is smoothly conjugate to an isometric action.

This should be a remark about how the hyperbolisation theorem also holds for non-orientable manifolds, but I'm puzzeld at how the irreducibility condition is dropped. I don't understand this theorem implies (1). Can anybody explain me?

Comment: Well, it is a mistake in the remark (assuming you quote them correctly) and counter-examples are easy to find...

Comment: It would not be the only mistake in their book regarding foundational issues, cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3132223/homotopically-vs-geometrically-atoroidal/3135160#3135160

Comment: Thank you. To show that reducible is a necessary hypothesis, can we use the fact that hyperbolic manifolds are aspherical?

Comment: Sure, that's one way to see this.